# Apparent Memory Leak in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, memory-leaks

How do you force a DataGridView to release its reference to a bound DataSet?

We have a rather large dataset being displayed in a DataGridView and noticed that resources were not being freed after the DataGridView was closed.  If the user repeatedly views this report they eventually get an out of memory exception.  ANTS Memory Profiler confirmed that the DGV is holding a reference despite `dgv.DataSource` being set to null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to forcing the DataGridView to release resources is to do the binding through the intermediary object `BindingSource`.

The code then looks something like this:

```
...
DataGridView dgvQueryResults;
DataTable m_dataTable;
BindingSource m_binder;

public void PopulateView()
{
  ...
  // Bind the data source through and intermediary BindingSource
  m_binder.DataSource = m_dataTable;
  dgvQueryResults.DataSource = m_binder;
  ...
}


/// <summary>
/// Frees lindering resources. Sets data bindings to null and forces 
/// garbage collection.
/// </summary>
private void ResetDataGridView()
{
  dgvQueryResults.DataSource = null;

  if (null != m_binder) m_binder.DataSource = null;
  m_binder = null;

  dataTable = null;

  // Force garbage collection since this thing is a resource hog!
  GC.Collect ();

  m_binder = new BindingSource ();
}

...
```

Comment: There are lots of good reasons to use the `BindingSource`, but this isn't one of them.  If objects aren't being disposed because they're registered with events, using a `BindingSource` isn't addressing the problem at all.  Also:  there are seldom good reasons to call `GC.Collect()`, and this is not one of them.

Comment: Using BindingSource was suggested by Microsoft here: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=92260

Calling `GC.Collect()` is necessary in this case because the user may click through reports faster than the GC frees resources and the app will soon crash with an out of memory exception.  Granted though, the reporting function could be rewritten to play a little nicer.

BTW, this whole thing came about as a result of the classic not testing with a realistic data set 8]

Answer (score 3):

Do you have any events registered on the DataGridView like OnClick?  Make sure you unregister all events, otherwise it will not be garbage collected

Comment: That isn't *quite* true; it is the `DataGridView` that can see **out** via its events - so if the `DataGridView` is being disposed its events will be nullified. A better question is: what can see the (old) `DataGridView`...

Comment: Yes, there are numerous events.  I had read this elsewhere, but it didn't seem to be the cause.

Answer (score 3):

Call this to clear `DataGridView1`:

```
datagridview1.DataSource = null;
datagridview1.Rows.Clear();
GC.Collect();
```

How I use it?

I imported data from to `DataGridView1` and then studied the content and transferred it to `DataGridView2`.

So it used 2.4GB of memory and then, after calling `Clear`, it dropped to normal - for me to 128KB.

Answer (score 3):

We've seen this behavior with datagridviews that have a datasource that contains a lot of images where the datagridview gets loaded repeatedly. Setting the DataSource for the datagridview to null and doing a Dispose on the datasource and a GC.Collect prior to each load seems to handle the leak.

Answer (score 1):

Are you closing down the entire `Form`? or just the `DataGridView`? I'm wondering if this is some caching in the `BindingContext`. You could try using a new binding-context per `DataGridView`?

Also; as always, double check events etc - in particular any using captured variables, as that is a subtle way of adding a dependency (note the capture scopes mean you might be capturing more than you think if you have complex anonymous methods / lambdas).

You might need to drop into profilers or windbg to find the remaining reference.

Comment: The data grid is on a form that gets closed each time.  When the user runs new a report a new instance is created.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't set the DataGridView to null.  You should call dispose on the DataGridView instead to allow it to properly clean itself up instead of adding more work to the GC to handle it.

Also, if you have any rooted references to the DataGridView, it will never be disposed (even if you call Dispose()).  The GC thinks it's still alive.  You should check for any rooted references to it - i.e. event handlers, static reference, etc. and remove those first before calling Dispose().